# Regexp to wrap expression with find and replace

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

In string like this:

To be **against** something is to be touching it or opposed to it.
→  They both leaned **against** the wall.

I need to select symbols before the arrow "→" and wrap it in  tag.

To select symbols I used regex in FIND

```
.+?(?=→)
```

To wrap the expression in the tag I used regex in REPLACE

```
<span>\1</span>
```

But it doesn't work.

How to fix it?

Comment: Use `<span>$0</span>`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\1` placeholder refers to the capturing group #1 pattern, but yours have none defined.

You may refer to the whole match with `$0` placeholder:

```
<span>$0</span>
```

Else, you need to wrap the part before the arrow with the capturing group, `(.+?)(→)`, and replace with `<span>\1</span>\2` (or `<span>$1</span>$2`).

Note that `\n` POSIX style backreferences can only refer to Group 1 through 9.